# TChromeTabs on Delphi 7: bad rendering of images in Tabs

Tags: delphi-7

I am using `TChromeTabs` by [Paul Spencer Thornton](https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs) on Delphi 7 and I have a problem that I cannot solve: when I want to display images in `TChromeTab`, they are displayed with poor graphics, with [few colors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbKWp.png)

However, the images are [displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fvzic.png) in the Object Inspector, and if I open the `TImageList` component, the images are [also displayed correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jV0qK.png) here, even when the application is running.

Notice that the first time I opened the `TImageList` editor this [hint message appeared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imCby.png) and I answered *Yes*. If in the same dialog box instead I answer *No*, the images appear [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hpkPr.png) (on a black background) .

The project is `ChromeTabsDemoD7.dpr` downloaded from the [developer's site](https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs/tree/master/Demo).

I couldn't find a solution to this problem anywhere online, and I don't know how to fix it, can anyone help me?

I did an alternative test with a new application, with a `TPageControl` and a `TImageList`: loading the `TImageList` with images and setting the `ImageIndex` property of a `TTabSheet`, the image appears drawn correctly on the tab (I cannot post the sample screen due to forum limitations for newly registered users).

Note: Delphi 7 with [CnPack](http://www.cnpack.org).

Comment: I don't know the solution but I can confirm seeing the same problem on Delphi 7 here. Why don' you raise the issue with the developer?
https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs/issues

Comment: @dougwoodrow Done https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs/issues/97

Answer (score 2):

[Issue number 10](https://github.com/norgepaul/TChromeTabs/issues/10) on the ChromeTabs repository holds the answer:

1. Get an external copy of pngImage

(the version provided with the [JVCL library](https://github.com/project-jedi/jvcl) seems to work fine)

2. Enable the following define in ChromeTabUtils:

   {$DEFINE USE_PNGIMAGE}

Comment: I can't rate the answer because I don't have the reputation yet >= 15 anyway thanks for your answer :)